# Sobreposição no label de um form

Tags: html, css

Olá 
 Eu tô um problema na formatação de form  em que input esta sobrepondo o label quando a tela e diminuída e eu queria que se posicionasse acima do input quando o tamanho da tela fosse diminuido.

**techo html**

```
 <div class="container_form_user">
            <label class="label_form" for="">E-Mail:
                  <input class="input_form_user" type="text">
            </label>
 </div>
```

**Estilo css**

```
    .container_form_user{
    max-width: 570px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;

}
.label_form{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px  0 10px;
    line-height: 37px;
    background-color:rosybrown;
}



.input_form_user{
    height:37px;
    max-width:420px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border-radius:5px;
    position: absolute;
    resize: none;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: O input tem o mesmo tamanho do label_form e está em absolute, como o label form tem uma margem em cima, o input não respeita essa margem como filho, então sobrepõe, tente colocar o position: absolute; para position: relative; no input

Comment: Eu tinha feito isso antes e deu certo,  porem o resultado que eu quero e que o input fique todo deslocado a direita e o label a esquerda isso em relação ao container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `input` é `inline` por natureza, então a minha sugestão é vc fazer um `@media` e colocar uma medida na qual o seu `input` vai mudar de `inline` pra `block`, assim ele vai *quebrar a linha* e ficar abaixo do texto. No caso eu defini que em telas de até 768px ele vai ficar na linha de baixo do texto, depois disso eles ficam na mesma linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o exemplo da imagem acima:

```css
    .container_form_user{
    max-width: 570px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;

}
.label_form{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px  0 10px;
    line-height: 37px;
    background-color:rosybrown;
}



.input_form_user{
    height:37px;
    max-width:420px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border-radius:5px;
    position: absolute;
    resize: none;
    right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .input_form_user {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container_form_user">
    <label class="label_form" for="">E-Mail:
        <input class="input_form_user" type="text">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigada pelo esclarecimento,  consegui resolver com sua solução.

Comment: @RichardCarlos fico feliz em ter ajudado!